# Why are Scala's `Lists` implemented as linked lists

Tags: list, scala, linked-list, immutability

I always thought that the benefit of linked lists was that you could add or remove items (especially not from the end) without having to copy lots of elements thanks to the beauty of pointers.

However, Scala's `List` is immutable (at least by default). What is the benefit of having an immutable linked list (because there are definite downsides, e.g. not O(1) element access.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the main reason is that one of the most powerful uses of linked lists is head/tail splitting.  There are lots of recursive algorithms that look like this one:

```
def listlen[A](xs: List[A], already: Int = 0): Int = xs match {
  case Nil => already
  case x :: rest => listlen(rest, already+1)
}
```

Of course, lists already know how to get their length; this is just an example.  The point is that you pull off the head, and then do something else with the tail--lots of useful things work this way.

Since lists are *immutable*, we can do something else--we can take as much time as we want to evaluating the rest of our list!  We don't have to finish in one go; we're sure it will never change.  This would not be the case if the list were mutable--either we need to lock the list, preventing anyone else from seeing it, or we need to make a defensive copy of the whole thing just in case someone might swap it.

Now, if you really want a mutable list, there's `mutable.LinkedList` that has the nice insertion properties that you're talking about.  But that doesn't give you the elegant recursion with peace of mind that the immutable lists give you.

(Note that you could do some of this with an immutable array-backed structure, but the possible benefit of a collection with each element wrapped is that you don't need to save or copy the whole array just because you need a few elements from the end; if the early elements in the list aren't pointed to any more, they can be garbage collected.)

Comment: LinkedList is just an inefficient data structure on nowadays hardware, each node is a cache-miss and there is nothing more expensive than a cache-miss.

Comment: @bestsss - Depends on the context.  Often, yes, you're right.  One should certainly be _suspicious_ of linked lists from a performance standpoint, unless they make it easy for you to use a more efficient algorithm (e.g. "don't need to make a defensive copy of a huge dataset").  But hardware is so fast these days that many tasks are limited by your ability to code it right, not the hardware's ability to run it quickly.  (But I would criticize linked lists for being non-parallelizable before complaining about the cache-miss.  Oh, and a page fault is still _way_ worse than a cache-miss.)

Comment: @Rex, swapping or accessing any IO will be even slower; you know I don't mean that. Picking LinkedList as default structure could be a huge performance hit for many tasks. I am comparing only a linked structure to a linear-based one. Linked structures are only useful to insert in the middle after a traverse. Circular lists can add at both ends w/o significant performance penalties. Also linked structures (incl. java.util.HashMap) have significantly higher footprint.

Comment: @bestsss - I think you're missing the point.  Sometimes you don't need to add at both ends, and sometimes immutability helps you easily write more efficient algorithms.  For those times, or when performance is less important than correctness, `List` is a great choice.  For other times (e.g. if you have to add at both ends) you may be better off choosing something else.

Comment: @Rex, I am only concerning linked vs linear-based (array) approach. Immutability can be achieved just as fine with an array backed data structure.

Comment: @bestsss - Repeated `cons` and `tail` (as with adding to and removing from a stack) is tricky to do efficiently with immutable array-backed structures.

Comment: Aren't stacks generally mutable :)? But `cons` makes sense. (`Tail` not so much, since an array will have a set length and O(1) access to any element.)

Comment: @aharon - If you only do one or the other, it's fine--for `tail` you can use a view into the array, and for `cons` you can prepend a block of elements and use a view into them.  But going back and forth doesn't work.

Comment: I really don't see how `cons` could be made `O(1)` with arrays (even mutable ones) unless you know in advance how many elements to expect. This information isn't always readily available. Trading crazy-fast cons for greater cache coherency isn't necessarily going to help performance.

Comment: @Kevin - It's amortized `O(1)` just like appending to `ArrayList`.  The only trick is that you add a view of that structure that only goes up to the element you just added.  If you can only add, your view is immutable.

Comment: @Rex I was thinking specifically about the requirement for a (small) constant time prepend on a structure that's still maximally cache-coherent following the prepend, I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: @Kevin - Prepend is just append looked at backwards.  And it's not maximally coherent, but it's `O(1)` coherent.  And yes, it's not small constant time, it's small _amortized_ constant time.  You can't do it with a constant time upper bound.

Answer (score 12):

Structural sharing.  If you perform a higher-order function (map, fold, etc) on the list, you return a new instance of a list that shares the pointers of the previous list.

Daniel Spiewak did a marvelous presentation about functional data structures at NE Scala last week.  See here:  http://www.nescala.org/2011/

Comment: Why can't you do that with something like an immutable `java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: I suppose you could use Google's com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList, which does not share structure with the list from which it was derived.  Doubles the memory, though.  Just make sure you don't use Collections.unmodifiableList, which returns a view of the mutable list where the data inside could still be changed.

Comment: @aharon A `java.util.ArrayList` is not immutable, ever. You can get an unmodifiable _view_ of it, but the original reference is still capable of changing it, so the library cannot depend on it never changing.

Comment: So you make something like an ArrayList that is mutable. ArrayList isn't very advanced, that wouldn't be too hard even for a beginning programmer.

Answer (score 9):

> However, Scala's List is immutable (at least by default). What is the benefit of having an immutable linked list

I'm a little late to the party here, but I felt there's an important point no one's made:

On top of what Rex Kerr said, it's worth pointing out that building a new list by prepending to an immutable singly linked list is a constant time operation. You just create a new node that points to the already existing list. Since the list is immutable you know the new tail won't ever change, and you don't need to copy any data.

The fact that you can build new, larger, but still immutable lists with a constant time operation, and with a small memory footprint(just the cost of one node) is, I suspect, a large part of the reason the data structure was chosen.

Answer (score 5):

`scala.List` is an alias for `scala.collection.immutable.List`. It is but one of many concrete collection implementations.

If you're coming from a Java background, equate `java.util.List` to `scala.collection.mutable.Buffer`, not to `scala.List`.

You can get an overview of the structure of the collections library in the [Scala 2.8 Collections Overview.](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html). Here you'll find many other concrete implementations (both mutable and immutable).

Answer (score -5):

While I have close to no idea how scala is implemented. LinkedLists should be avoided,though.

They are inefficient on current hardware due to traverse them each Node practically leads to a cache miss.
Cache misses are what governs nowadays performance.

Comment: What about code where performance isn't particularly important?  (And what fraction of code do you think that is?)

Comment: @Rex, I guess I don't understand the question. Implementing something via any approach must have reasoning behind. I am quite sure Scala guys participate a meeting dedicated on non-java languages running on JVMs to improve the performance.

Comment: @bestsss - I don't understand your reasoning.  Some Scala developers care about performance, therefore Linked Lists should always be avoided because they may cause cache misses?  Huh?  Maybe there _are cases where cache misses don't matter_ and maybe _people can care about two different things and want good solutions for both_.

Comment: @Rex, I meant the language architects.

Comment: @bestsss - I know what you meant.  But this fact is completely irrelevant to your statements about linked lists.

Comment: @bestsss - Can you support your "abstract" general assertion with some concrete performance numbers which come from some performance test cases on a particular Scala implementation? IOW, can you back up your mostly contextless assertion with actual performance testing results demonstrating the validity of your point? BTW, I am genuinely interested to know if you are on to something as I had a similar concern but have not yet had enough spare time to test and validate/invalidate my speculation.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium, I am not sure what you'd like me to show. if: that linked structures are generally outperformed by array backed ones, both memory footprint and time, well that should not be hard to prove. However, to write a micro benchmark to test, I am afraid it will be too biased. Here is an article form Intel on linked vs array based structures. Overall traversing a LinkedList is awfully slow compared to the same operation of an array. LinkedList is just bound to cache-misses.

Comment: If the elements of a linked list are put on the heap in a sensible way (i.e. close to another), you get less problems. That is, you have more an issue of memory management than of data structures.