# Why a list in Scala is LinkedList internally?

Tags: scala, list, linked-list, implementation

I am new to Scala and got to know that a list in Scala is a singly Linked List under the hood.

Here is the documentation for the same:

> A class for immutable linked lists representing ordered collections of elements of type A.
>
> This class comes with two implementing case classes scala.Nil and scala.:: that implement the abstract members isEmpty, head and tail.
>
> This class is optimal for last-in-first-out (LIFO), stack-like access patterns. If you need another access pattern, for example, random access or FIFO, consider using a collection more suited to this than List.

Why is it like that the list is a linked list internally?

Isn't it less effective in case a random access is required?

Comment: It is more efficient for some things, less efficient for some things. The last paragraph of your quote even tells you which. However, functional languages very often have programming patterns where linked lists work well.

Comment: Actually its not a `LinkedList` at all, it is a `Cons` List. It just happens to be that that `Cons` Lists are pretty similar to `LinkedList` when you look at the performance characteristics. There are multiple implementations of `Collection` other than `List` which will suit your needs better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Scala's \`Lists\` implemented as linked lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130097/why-are-scalas-lists-implemented-as-linked-lists)

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: "Actually it's not an apple at all, it's a fruit. It's just happens that fruits are pretty similar to apples". Every cons list is by definition a singly linked list (though not all linked lists are cons lists - e.g. doubly-linked lists).